# How can I have multiple tabs in a ubuntu terminal window for windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a new laptop with Windows 10. I have installed Ubuntu terminal from Microsoft store.

I used to be able to get multiple tabs in the same ubuntu window and split windows in same tab as well.

Now I couldn't find the + button on the tab and there is no drop down menu too. Not sure what I need to do to enable them. It works well in my old Windows 10 laptop.

The only difference is in old laptop, I install WSL manually and in new laptop I installed ubuntu terminal via Microsoft Store.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a question about the Microsoft console application being used, and I think that's off-topic here. Anyway: MS has a new Terminal app which is much more feature-full than the old console.exe: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701 You probably want that.

Answer (score 0):

While it is sometimes called "Ubuntu Terminal" (even by Canonical), the terminal app that Ubuntu on WSL uses by default is really simply the default *Windows* terminal application.

Under Windows 10, this is still the 20+ year old Windows Console Host (`conhost.exe`).  However, as @muru mentioned in the comments, you almost certainly had installed [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9n0dx20hk701) from the Microsoft Store on your old system.  This is the new replacement terminal from Microsoft that includes tabs, the dropdown menu that you mentioned, and much more.

Under Windows 11, this is now the default terminal (replacing the old `conhost.exe`), but Windows 10 users will still need to install and run it manually.

> The only difference is in old laptop, I install WSL manually and in new laptop I installed ubuntu terminal via Microsoft Store.

That honestly doesn't make a difference with the Terminal.  At some point on your old system, you must have installed Windows Terminal separately - It is never bundled with the Ubuntu application in the Store.